# How to correctly unset an array from UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am new to swift and learning about `UserDefaults`. When a user logs into my application, I am storing a key to check if he is 'logged in' and I unset this key every time the user logs out.

I save it and unset it as:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
```

I also save an array with the user's details. I want to know how I can unset this when the log out button is pressed?

The code for saving the details is:

```
let array = [storedUsername, storedFirstname, storedSurname, storedUniName, storedUniCourse, storedEmail];         
UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "UserDetailsArray");
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
```

I have tried to remove them by:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "UserDetailsArray")
```

But this doesn't work, so I wanted to know what is the correct way for doing this? Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is the complete function I call when logging out. The objective is to remove the array of the users details + also to set `UserLoggedIn` to `false`

```
@IBAction func LogoutButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "UserDetailsArray")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController", sender: self);
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Nothing happens, the values are not unset. I say that because when I login again, the old values are present

Comment: Do you call `synchronize` between `removeObject` and quit?

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete function I call when logging out and unsetting the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be a bug somewhere maybe because I was setting UserDefaults for the first time? I'm not sure. Anywhere I included this snippet before I save anything and removed it after running it **once** in the code:

```
if let bundle = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundle)
}
```

It seemed to do the trick! The information saves and retrieves perfectly now